# SAS macro do loop-- import multiple flat files

Tags: import, macros, sas, sas-macro

I have a list of 17 flat files that I'm trying to import into different data sets. All of the files have the same data step, so I'm trying to write a do while loop to import all the files.

I've been trying to adapt some code from here without success:
http://www.sas.com/offices/europe/uk/support/sas-hints-tips/tips-enterprise-csv.html

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543785.htm

I'm getting an error that says the `%do statement is not valid in open code`. Here is my code:

```
% let path1 = 'c:\path1'
% let path2 = 'c:\path2'
...
% let pathN = 'c:\pathN' 

%let n=1; 

%do %while (&n <= 17);
%let pathin = &path&n;

  data retention&n;
    infile &pathin;
    <data step-->
  run;

%let n=%eval(&n+1); 
%end;
```

I've tested the data step outside of the do-while loop and it works fine for 1 file at a time using the `%let pathin = &path&n` code. The code still writes the datafile for the 1st data set; but, I need to be able to loop through all the files and can't figure out how. Sorry if this is a novice question; I'm just learning SAS.

Thanks,
-Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SAS programming!  The error message you got is a clue.  "Open code" refers to statements that are executed directly by the SAS system.  A `%do` statment is part of the **SAS Macro Language**, not "normal" SAS.  A `%let` statement can be executed in open code and is use to create a `macro variable` (distinct from a compiled macro).

Compiled SAS macros are created by code that appears between the `%macro` and `%mend` statements.  For example, using your code:

```
%macro run_me;
%let n=1; 

%do %while (&n <= 17);
%let pathin = &path&n;

  data retention&n;
    infile &pathin;
    <data step-->
  run;

%let n=%eval(&n+1); 
%end;
%mend;
```

But all that does is define/compile the macro.  To execute it, you must issue the statement `%run_me;`.  Note that the name `run_me` was just a name I made up.

For more info, please consult the [SAS Macro Reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm), especially the introductory section.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your progma to macro, turn your macro variables declared by `LET` statement into macro arguments:

```
%macro readfile(n, pathin);

  data retention&n;
    infile &pathin;
    <data step-->
  run;

%mend;
```

A data step to repetitively call your macro.
Here the data included in `CARDS` statement, but also can be read from some table via `SET` statement.
The macro call is performed via `call execute` routine.

```
data _null_;
length path $200 stmt $250;
input path;
stmt = catt('%readfile(', putn(_N_, 3. -L), path, ')');
call execute(stmt);

cards;
c:\file1.txt
c:\file2.txt
c:\file3.txt
;
run;
```